# \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 вместо текста

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import re
f = open('dir.txt')
a = f.read()
t = re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', a)
```

Вытаскиваю названия папок из текстового документа, получаю массив. 
Когда в названии папки попадается кириллица получается вот это

> `['Games', 'Intel', 'PerfLogs', 'Program Files', 'Program Files (x86)',
>   'Python27', 'Python273', 'radare2', 'Users', 'Windows',
>   '\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82']`

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Укажите версию Python. Я предполагаю, что версия Python 2, и проблема специфична именно для него. Для Python 3 будет другая проблема, и решать ее нужно будет по-другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строку надо декодировать в UTF-8:

```
>>> b'\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82'.decode("utf-8")
'тест тест'
```

Comment: у меня при выполнении кода ошибка LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001

Comment: я написал таким образом print(t[10].decode("utf-8")) 10й элемент у меня тест тест. При выполнении ошибка LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102954/discussion-between-victor-says-reinstate-monica-and-insolor).